# converting a mysql Datetime stamp to a month using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

How can I get  a MySQL datetime stamp converted to a month using JavaScript?

MySQL date : 2021-12-14 10:15:56

output : December

using JavaScript code

I tried this

const moonLanding = new Date('2021-12-14 10:15:56');
// const moonLanding = new Date('July 20, 69 00:20:18');

console.log(moonLanding.getMonth());
output is > 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toLocaleString() method like this:

```js
const timestamp = '2021-12-14 10:15:56';
const date = new Date(timestamp);

const monthName = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });

console.log(monthName);
```

Comment: That is operating precisely like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct.
December is the 11th month, if you consider a zero based index.
According to the documentation, January is month 0, which would make December month 11:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth